# How to animate first item loaded using jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, animation, load

I am using the load function for my links to load html files inside a div. I also use slideDown to animate the content, but it doesn't work for the first html loaded. How can I fix that?

http://jsfiddle.net/QNQv9/1/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".iframe").on("click", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $iframe.load($(this).attr('href'));
        $iframe.slideDown(500)
      });   
});
```

Comment: Can u explain ur question more precisely ??

Comment: Sorry, what I want is the slideDown animation to play after the html is loaded , then reveal the content. Right now the first time I hit a link the html content just "pops" and the slide animation is not executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your jsfiddle you have 'Same Origin Policy' issue. 
*XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://jsfiddle.net/. Origin http://fiddle.jshell.net is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.*

You need to do the animation in the callback function. Try this ,

```
$iframe.load($(this).attr('href'), function() {
  $iframe.slideDown(500)
});
```

Comment: Thanks but still it doesn't work though. First html that loads just pops up instead of sliding down.

Comment: You need to hide the $iframe initially before calling `load`..that way you can see the smooth animation

Comment: You can accomplish this pretty easily by putting `.hide()` before the `.load()`.

Comment: There is an issue though(only when using slideDown - fade works better). If I hide the $iframe the parent div goes to 0 height then the $iframe loads so the animation is missed. I can't use fixed height because the content is dynamic(different html files with different height). Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe instead of using `.hide()`, you can try `$iframe.slideUp(200)` ?

Comment: Yeah this seemed to work, great! Now there is another issue on the functionality though. If you click a link after the first html is loaded, then the "heights" are getting confused and the slide animations mix up. It's hard to explain but is there a way to reset the height to the html's default every time a link is hit so this doesn't occur?

Comment: $iframe.empty() worked this out, but is it possible to animate it?

Answer (score 1):

RE your height issue,

what you can do is load the $iframe after you sliding up,

**EDITED**

```
var link = $(this).attr('href');

$iframe.slideUp(200, function() {
   $iframe.html(''); //You don't need this line
   $iframe.load(link, function() {
      $iframe.slideDown(500)
   });
});
```

Comment: Actually, I tried this approach but it doesn't function as I want it to. Using empty alone works though: `$iframe.slideUp(500, function(){$iframe.empty()})`

Comment: Thanks for letting know!

Comment: rAjA, there is a problem. I uploaded it on a server so when loading speeds occur the animations do not work. I tried using your method, which slides after the content is loaded but it doesn't work(basically the load function doesn't execute).

Comment: Oh it should be working..did you get any errors in the console? Also check whether you got the correct `link` before `.load` ..

Comment: Actually it works but if the connection is slow, the animations do not even display. (I am simulating connection speed using software). This is what happens: the animation plays but you can't see it because the html content is being loaded(and drawed into the screen). Only if the html content is saved into the cache the animations are smooth. Any ideas?

Comment: I suppose we need to not display the html content until they are fully loaded, then animate. Is that possible?